# Search form with 2 input fields with different filterable classes upon search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have this code to filter out text div's upon search.

The first input would filter out by the 'name' & 'sku' classes. The second would then filter out by 'location'.

When trying to filter by location it would display all divs with the searched location, but I need it to correlate to the first inputs search. I also need to add a button that would carry out the search function once clicked instead of having it automatically filter out upon search.

I would then also need them to sort price lowest to highest by means of a dropdown but I have no idea on how to get this done.

Could someone please assist.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'all') {
      $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
      var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
      $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
    }
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })

  var $search = $("#search").on('input', function() {
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    let value = $(this).val();

    $('.box').show().not(function() {
      return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test($(this).find('.name, .sku').text());
    }).hide();
  });

  var $search = $("#search-location").on('input', function() {
    $btns.removeClass('active');
    let value = $(this).val();

    $('.box').show().not(function() {
      return new RegExp(value, 'gi').test($(this).find('.location').text());
    }).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
    <input type="text" id="search-location" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by location">
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="parent">
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Pepsi </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
      <p class="location">east</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Cocacola </p>
      <p class="sku">D-1314</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
      <p class="location">north</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Mountien Dwe </p>
      <p class="sku">D-458</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
      <p class="location">north</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Burger </p>
      <p class="sku">F-125</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
      <p class="location">north</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
      <p class="sku">F-7412</p>
      <p>$ 2,410</p>
      <p class="location">south</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74122</p>
      <p>$ 2,4105</p>
      <p class="location">east</p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box location-box food">
    <center>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
      <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
      <p class="sku">F-74112</p>
      <p>$ 2,4103</p>
      <p class="location">north</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are applying the filter on the `.box` class for each search field. So the typing on the 2nd field was overriding the results.

My assumption is you want to search the results matching either name/sku AND location. In case you meant OR condition, you just need to change the logic a bit.

Searching on typing is more intuitive, but if you really need the search button, then your code should become simpler. You don't need to implement `.on()` for each search input.

Also, added the logic for the sort. However, it would recommend sorting the result on the input data set. I am sure you are generating the list from some javascript variable which would be populated via some api call or data fetch function. With the current functionality, the sort will only be applied upon sorting, the initial data may not be sorted.

```js
var elems;
$(document).ready(function () {
    elems = $(".drink, .food");
});

function search() {
    let nameSkuVal = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
    let locVal = $("#search-location").val().toLowerCase();

    var finalElems = elems.filter(function () {
        name = $(this).find(".name").text().toLowerCase();
        sku = $(this).find(".sku").text().toLowerCase();
        loc = $(this).find(".location").text().toLowerCase();

        return (nameSkuVal ? name.includes(nameSkuVal) || sku.includes(nameSkuVal) : true) && (locVal ? loc.includes(locVal) : true);
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        n1 = parseFloat($(a).find(".price").text().replace("$ ", "").replace(",", ""));
        n2 = parseFloat($(b).find(".price").text().replace("$ ", "").replace(",", ""));
        return (n1 < n2) ? -1 : (n1 > n2) ? 1 : 0;
    });

    $('#parent').html(finalElems);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by name or sku">
        <input type="text" id="search-location" class="form-control" placeholder="Search product by location">
        <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" id="parent">
    <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Pepsi </p>
            <p class="sku">D-1251</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,415</p>
            <p class="location">east</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Cocacola </p>
            <p class="sku">D-1314</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">north</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box drink">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Mountien Dwe </p>
            <p class="sku">D-458</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">north</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box food">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Burger </p>
            <p class="sku">F-125</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">north</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box food">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Hot Dog </p>
            <p class="sku">F-7412</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,410</p>
            <p class="location">south</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box food">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Hot Dog 2</p>
            <p class="sku">F-74122</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,4105</p>
            <p class="location">east</p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 box location-box food">
        <center>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" class="" alt="">
            <p class="name">Hot Dog 2233</p>
            <p class="sku">F-74112</p>
            <p class="price">$ 2,4103</p>
            <p class="location">north</p>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should mark divs with adding "**someAdditionalClass**" then remove "**someAdditionalClass**" which is not found in text filter, when you search by name or sku.
then when you search after filter, you should search by **box.someAdditionalClass**. here is  your working code.

```
 var $search = $("#search").on("input", function () {
      $btns.removeClass("active");
      let value = $(this).val();

      $(".box")
        .show()
        .addClass("someAdditionalClass")
        .not(function () {
          return new RegExp(value, "gi").test(
            $(this).find(".name, .sku").text()
          );
        })
        .removeClass("someAdditionalClass")
        .hide();
    });


 var $search = $("#search-location").on("input", function () {
      $btns.removeClass("active");
      let value = $(this).val();

      $(".box.someAdditionalClass")
        .show()
        .not(function () {
          return new RegExp(value, "gi").test(
            $(this).find(".location").text()
          );
        })
        .hide();
    });
```

working example on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zaLd08h5/

I also added your missing buttons :)

Comment: Thanks for this Bertan. I actually meant something in the form of this https://jsfiddle.net/zuh_fiddl3/1eo5q2nf/1/ Although I can't get the  'sku' bar to work in the search